# Embed the web application in to the windows application

Tags: windows, web-applications

I have a web application, I would like to embed the web application in the window application..

Like if i click the icon in the windows, it should open a window along with that site.. 
Need to disable the right click and menu properties and every thing..

Some one told that we can do it via .Net..
Is there any other way to do that.. 
Could you please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed a WebBrowser control on a windows form.  From there you can do a lot of things such as access the DOM and actually control the browser.  Microsoft has a **[nice overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28VS.85%29.aspx)** although that is for C++/VB programmers.  The **[.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)** might help you translate from one to the other.  And there is a **[decent beginner's tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebBrowserInCSMDB12022005001524AM/WebBrowserInCSMDB.aspx)** at c-sharpcorner.